# Can't find "install" option for Dropbox installation

Tags: software-installation, dropbox

I have been trying to install Dropbox from the software center but I can't find the "install" option, it only shows the "use this source" option. I also tried to install it via terminal and still failed.

Comment: Did you try to download it from dropbox site and install? https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx

Answer (score 1):

First you have to enable repository and **update from ppa**.

[`dropbox`](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/dropbox?dist=trusty) is available from main repository for 14.04. so run following command in terminal to enable main & universe repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe"
```

> The **main** component contains applications that are free software, can be freely redistributed and are fully supported by the Ubuntu team. & The **universe** component is a snapshot of the free, open-source, and Linux world.

Then setup key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
```

Then setup repository:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ trusty main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dropbox.list'
```

Then update and install:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install dropbox
```

After that you can launch it from dash:

[image: screen]

I have tested it and worked for me. Hope it helps.

---

**Note**: If your Ubuntu version is not trusty then change "release-name" in 
    `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ <release-name> main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dropbox.list'` at setting up repository. You can also run `$(lsb_release -sc)` to find release-name.

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/<release-main>/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to linux.dropbox.com:http:

I keep getting this error messages "W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tucan/unstable/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:"

Comment: Did you replace <release-name>with your release name (e.g., trusty)?

Comment: @amc No,i downloaded it from the dropbox site

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are using nautilus as your file manager, open a terminal and write

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

(or search for that package in the software center)
this shpuld then install dropbox automatically

Answer (score 0):

From Terminal use the following command,

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

If you have an no Dropbox indicator in the top panel use the following command,

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

Once installed restart.